# chrome extension with flutter and message passing

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i am working on chrome extension with flutter, i have to make api calls but from flutter api calls are not working so i tried to invoke a JS native method that send a message to extension in service worker and in service worker call the api and got response, now i want to send the response back to flutter. is there any way to implement this ? am i doing correct or not ?

i also tried this https://pub.dev/packages/chrome_extension package but not getting response onMessage listener, gets error in chrome extension.

Comment: Use one-time messaging as shown in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) and [this example](/a/55292071).

Comment: @wOxxOm message sending is in working but i want to send data back from service worker to flutter ...

Comment: The links in my comment show how to send the data back.

Comment: I maintain the chrome_extension package. If you have any issue with it, consider creating a github ticket with a reproducible example.

Comment: @Xavier thanks alot for the chrome extension plugin, its my fault, i tried a lot and just not given a try to sending a one-time message as from above comments wOxxOm mentioned. Thanks.